# can a BLE Manufacturer Identifiert be used as a 16-Bit Service UUID

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

The BLE standard specifies that there are 16-Bit and 128-Bit Service UUIDs. The 16-Bit Service UUIDs are reserved by the BLE standard.

Additionally 16-Bit Manufacturer Identifiers can be purchased from the Bluetooth standard organisation.

I have come across a situation where a device advertised a 16-Bit Manufacturer Identifier as a Service. Looking at the assigned numbers document the range of Manufacturer Identifiers indeed does not intersect with the range of 16-Bit Service UUIDs (0x1800 to 0x1857, vs 0x000 to 0x0D21), however I cannot find any mention that it is "legal" or intended to work like this and am looking for clarification.

Assigned numbers:
https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/an/

Comment: No, you can not. Lower UUIDs are reserved for other purposes such as protocol UUID. For example SDP protocol UUID is 0x0001, RFCOMM 0x0003, etc.